# Error in setting bin grouping using cut Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, cut

I try to group my dataset to different bin size with the function cut,

```
cuts <- apply(rd, 4, cut, c(-Inf, seq(10, 80, 10), Inf), labels=10:90)
```

but this error pops out:

> Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I guess it's because some of my value just matches the cutoff value, can anyone please teach me how to modify my code so that if it matches it will go to the group `>=` the value??

Comment: Do you have a 4D array?

Comment: No, I just wanna group them with different latitude range

Comment: So, what does the 4 refer to in `apply(rd, 4,`

Comment: the 4th column of my data.frame is the latitude... am i doing the correct thing?

Comment: You are doing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are using `cut` on the 4th column

```
cut(rd[,4], breaks= c(-Inf, seq(10, 80, 10), Inf), labels=10:90)
```

---

The `apply` methods are used for matrices with > one dimension.  Here, we are only using the 4th column, so the function can be directly applied on the `vector`.

Comment: Thanks @akrun . So I want the bin size as 10 degree. Is it like this: `cuts <- cut(rd[, 4], breaks=c(-Inf, seq(10,80,10), Inf), labels=seq(10,90,10))`

Comment: @wwwwwwww   Yes, it could be that.